# Azure Devops Pipelines task conditions on other job tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline yaml that has 2 jobs (ubuntu and macos)
I want this task(TASK1_MACOS) from JOB2 to depend on the task on JOB1 (TASK1_UBUNTU) but also want to run JOB1 and JOB2 on parallel.

So whenever TASK1_UBUNTU is still running... Do not run TASK1_MACOS

```
- job: JOB1
        displayName: 'UBUNTU'
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              # Write your commands here
              echo 'Hello world';
                sleep 30;
          displayName: TASK1_UBUNTU

- job: JOB2
        displayName: 'MACOS'
        pool:
          vmImage: macOS-12
        
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              # Write your commands here
              echo 'Hello world';
          displayName: TASK1_MACOS
```

so far as i know, the conditions are only specific within the jobs.

Comment: Jobs be default run in parallel. Would defining mac0s job to be dependent on the Ubuntu job give you the desired affect?

Comment: having the depondsOn condition will make macOS be dependent on Ubuntu so they won't run in parallel. My goal is to have ubuntu and macos run on parallel (which as you mentioned already is by default) but also, be able to add a condition in the task from macos to be dependent on ubuntu's task.

essentially, on ubuntu, i am building the artifact needed for macOS.. while the artifact is building ,i want macOS tasks to be also running until the download artifact task is reached..  so that way it would reduce the build time.